# Downloading PDFs

Tags: 8.0, pdf

I can download the majority of PDFs fine from any source; however, I've found that I can't download some specific PDFs.  For example, when I download either the [Network Railcard application form](http://www.network-railcard.co.uk/download/clientfiles/files/NetworkRailcardWebAppFormMar2014.pdf) or the [Network Railcard area](http://www.network-railcard.co.uk/download/clientfiles/files/map.pdf) PDFs from http://www.network-railcard.co.uk, I get the 'tap to open' screen, but then nothing happens... I can download the same PDF from a different source.

Has anyone else experienced anything similar, or have any suggestions what the cause (or fix) might be?

Comment: Works for me, on a Lumia 1020 running the Cyan update (8.1) - what phone/OS version are you using?

Comment: Yeh, sorry, should have stated: Lumia 820 on 8 (OS version 8.0.10517)

Comment: I've occasionally come across pdf's that won't open on the phone but I haven't been able to work out anything they had in common.

Comment: If I may, which PDF reader are you using?  There are multiple choices available.